# How to prompt a message is app already exist in Android

Tags: android

I want to display an alert message on installing a non-market App. For example, If I have an App "ABC" installed in my phone and I want to install its latest version, So on installing, I want to prompt a message "ABC App of is already installed, Do you want to install its latest version ?". If user clicks on yes button, latest App should start installing else installation is terminated.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your app, use this

```
PackageInfo pkg = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pkg.versionName;
 int Vcode = pkg.versionCode;
```

You get the version code of app. Now use a if condition to  compare your app version with old version and set alert dialog. Else no alert dialog.

Comment: Where should I mention this code in my App? It has to come without opening the application but if I write this in an activity It'll not work without opening that activity

Comment: It is not possible to have this prompt message automatically. The app should open and ask for the alert. How will the old version know that the new version has been installed without any running service or server support.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Now, on android phones if latest version of an application is about to install, android itself prompt a dialog box. on that a list of new permissions needed and an ok also a cancel button . So, you dont have to do it by yourself. :)